# How to deploy a web app to azure-mobile.net?

Tags: mobile, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an azure mobile services account and that gives me .azure-mobile.net web site URL for accessing mobile services APIs using REST.

I would like to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app to that domain which is basically the admin web site for my mobile app.

Using VS 2013, I am able to deploy to an azure web site .azurewebsites.net. But I would like to keep all stuff in the same domain. How can I deploy a web app to .azure-mobile.net ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't!

`azure-mobile.net` is reserved for mobile services projects. The same way `cloudapp.net` is reserved for cloud services and `azurewebsites.net` for Azure Web Sites.

As for keeping stuff under same domain, I would use my own domain. The only small deviation from this mantra is that currently there is no support for custom domain for Mobile Services. While the compute and storage services (Cloud Services, Virtual Machines, Web Sites, Storage Accounts) do support custom domains. The good thing is that Mobile services also support CORS, so you shall not have issues consuming your APIs from another domain via JavaScript.

Learn more about:

- [HTML5 and Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-get-started/).
- [Custom Domains for Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)
- [Custom Domains for Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/)
- [Custom Domains for Storage Accounts](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/)